# 18.04 eGPU setup working, but login loop when eGPU disconnected

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu-driver

After a year of relative stability, my eGPU setup went FUBAR.
Things started going awry soon after I updated the kernel on ubuntu 16.04.

So I decided to upgrade the distro to 18.04, and got my eGPU working again by instaling Nvidia's 390 drivers and blacklisting the Nouveau drivers, BUT the disconnected laptop (without GPU connected through thunderbolt) would be stuck in a login loop.
When I unblacklist Nouveau, then I got both the connected eGPU setup broken and disconnected laptop loop login.

The situation is I can get the eGPU setup working, but my laptop is useless on its own.
I cant get passed the login loop.

In `/var/log/syslog`, there's the following suspicious entry after booting without the GPU:

```
*gpu-manager[805]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/updates/dkms*
```

on Dell xps-13 9360 with GeForce GTX760 connected through thunderbolt;
Nvidia drivers: 390

**xorg.conf content:**

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 390.87  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64- 
rhel04-14)  Tue Aug 21 17:33:38 PDT 2018

Section "ServerLayout"
   Identifier     "Layout0"
   Screen      0  "Screen0"
   InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
   InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
   # generated from default
   Identifier     "Mouse0"
   Driver         "mouse"
   Option         "Protocol" "auto"
   Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
   Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
   Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
   # generated from default
   Identifier     "Keyboard0"
   Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   Identifier     "Monitor0"
   VendorName     "Unknown"
   ModelName      "Unknown"
   HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
   VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
   Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier     "Device0"
   Driver         "nvidia"
   VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier     "Screen0"
   Device         "Device0"
   Monitor        "Monitor0"
   DefaultDepth    24
   SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: When you wish to use the laptop on it's own type `sudo prime-select intel` and reboot. Later when you want to reconnect eGPU type `sudo prime-select nvidia` and reboot.

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I ended up reinstalling Bionic Beaver along with the nvidia drivers BUT I never used the nvidia-settings, so no /etc/X11/xorg.conf was ever written. So far so good, I dont have to set any prime-select values to switch from mobile to stationary mode, and didnt have to blacklist nouveau either. 
So working situation is:
1- no /etc/X11/xorg.conf file
2- the only xorg conf is found under /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
For anyone with the same problem, I would advise against using nvidia-settings and only use the default Bionic Beaver display settings (not Displays).

Comment: worth noting (or not): the latest ubuntu 18 install I did was a minimal install. No idea if it had an impact or not on this.

Comment: I'm glad it's working now. You might want to post an answer (instead of comments) so others can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I ended up reinstalling Bionic Beaver along with the nvidia drivers BUT I never used the nvidia-settings, so no /etc/X11/xorg.conf was ever written. So far so good, I dont have to set any prime-select values to switch from mobile to stationary mode, and didnt have to blacklist nouveau either. So working situation is: 1- no /etc/X11/xorg.conf file 2- the only xorg conf is found under /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ For anyone with the same problem, I would advise against using nvidia-settings and only use the default Bionic Beaver display settings (not Displays).